# Compare Number of Rows of Tables

Tags: oracle, postgresql, count

I have two or more tables different by structure and I want to compare their numbers of rows, which I get with the count-star query:

```
select count(*) from table_a
```

For two tables I would like to see the difference of the count-star-queries, for example. If this difference is 0, then the tables have the same number of rows.

For more tables you can calculate an average of the count-star queries (or something more meaningful than the average, up to you) and compare the single count-star's with this value. The main point is that, if all the N tables have the same size, I have as result N columns (or rows) filled with 0's. If the tables have not the same number of rows, then in each of the N columns (or rows) I expect to see the difference of the number of rows of a given table and the average (or something more meaningful, cf. above).

I have this problem on an Oracle DB but I could need this query on PostgreSQL in the future, probably we will migrate.

The most efficient the query is, the coolest, of course. Please comment on this also if you want.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your problem at all. "The main point is that 0 means that the count-star's are the expected ones." How do you know what the expected value is?

Comment: If you have two tables, 0 means their count-star is equal. If you have more than two tables, 0 for the column of table T means that the count-star of table T equals the average or whatever you choose to compare tables.

Comment: I think this should be re-opened with the update.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks. Do you know if we can somehow message the blockers?

Comment: @GismoRanas: [There are no "blockers", that's not how it works.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question) Users with enough reputation can vote to reopen. With enough votes the answer is reopened. Or an admin can do it. To help your cause you might want to edit the snide remarks on Oracle. Those are no well received around here, we all try to get along. Concentrate on the facts of the matter.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Ok, so let's say that today I fell in love with Oracle, but it won't last long, I guess. Oracle is a cooler name than PostgreSQL anyway, I like more snake goddesses than french neoclassical painters in berkley sauce.

Comment: Now, don't you insult the eternal beauty of "PostgreSQL". j/k. At least it's great for searching on the internets.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter The name could have been better, man. Post- is a really out of fashion prefix and you don't put -SQL at the end. Then all java packages should end with Java? Like GuavaJava, MockitoJava, lambdajJava? And that -gre- in the middle is really unexpressive. I feel Godwin is approaching, do you also?

Comment: @GismoRanas: it's not "Post", "gre" and "SQL" it's "Postgres" and  "SQL" and the duplicated s is dropped. I think they should simply consider writing it differently: "PostgresQL", instead of "PostgreSQL" (because they can't really change the name any more)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't know what it is, that's how it sounds to me. Anyway, before we start a civil war, apart from the name I think Postgres is the coolest think on the market.

Comment: I'll be happy to vote for reopening if you explain what you want. Can you tell us what you want as result, if for example you have just 4 tables with 2, 7, 10 and 11 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subquery with `UNION ALL` and the [aggregate function `avg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) used as window aggregate function should do the trick:

```
SELECT tbl::text, ct, round(ct - avg(ct) OVER (), 2) AS deviation
FROM  (
   SELECT tableoid::regclass AS tbl, count(*) AS ct FROM t GROUP BY 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT tableoid, count(*) FROM tbl GROUP BY 1
   -- UNION ALL ...
   ) sub
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8d2d8/2)